# happybase installation test error

Tags: python, happybase

After what seemed like a successful installation using the guide on this site:  [happybase docs[1](https://happybase.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)
I tried the test to verify installation worked but that resulted in an error.

This is the error -

```
 Successfully built happybase thriftpy ply
 Installing collected packages: six, ply, thriftpy, happybase
 Successfully installed happybase-1.1.0 ply-3.10 six-1.10.0 thriftpy 
 -0.3.9
(envname) [root@thrift-test ~]# python -c 'import happybase'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named happybase
```

Any advice appreciated.

EDIT: details on the setup - happybase installed on the server that will run python scripts. HBASE and thrift installed on a separate server.

EDIT: answer to comment:
The python version is 2.7.5 and the installation went as follows;

```
virtualenv envname
New python executable in /root/envname/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /root/envname/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
[root@thrift-test ~]# source envname/bin/activate
(envname) [root@thrift-test ~]# pip install happybase
Collecting happybase
 Downloading happybase-1.1.0.tar.gz (40kB)
100% |ââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââ| 40kB 1.9MB/s
Collecting six (from happybase)
Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: Check what version of Python `python` resolves to on your machine, and that your installation actually targeted that version. This sort of issue can occur when multiple versions of Python coexist on one machine.

Comment: The python version is 2.7.5 and the installation went as follows;   virtualenv envname
New python executable in /root/envname/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /root/envname/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
[root@thrift-test ~]# source envname/bin/activate
(envname) [root@thrift-test ~]# pip install happybase
Collecting happybase
  Downloading happybase-1.1.0.tar.gz (40kB)
    100% |ââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââ| 40kB 1.9MB/s
Collecting six (from happybase)
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Comment: turns out I ran it again and it tested out ok